# Extract diagonals of each 2D square sub-array from a larger 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, diagonal

This is my first programming class and I'm very excited to learn Python for Data Science. I cannot figure out how to write a loop that returns all diagonal numbers in the matrix. Below is the code, how close or far off am I? Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
cols = 0

matrixA = np.array([[2,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,4], [6,0,0], [0,7,0], [0,0,8]])

for rows in range(6):
    if rows == cols:
        print(matrixA[rows, cols])
    cols = cols + 1
```

Comment: First, ask yourself "where do the elements 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 occur?", that will help provide you with the insight into getting the elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current solution does not work because it does not take into account the fact that `matrixA` is not square. You will have to take care that your indices do not run out of bounds. Running it gives:

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3
```

This is because the maximum value that `cols` is allowed to take here is `2`.

---

As an alternative, you could use [*`np.diag`*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
print(x)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [6, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 8]])

res = np.array([np.diag(x, -offset) for offset in range(0, *x.shape)])

print(res)
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

If you want a 1D result, call [*`np.ravel`*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
print(res.ravel())
array([2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: @roganjosh This works thank you! Can you break down the res code section? Sorry for the number of questions, I'm new to Python and truly appreciate the amount of feedback I get on here! Thank you!

Comment: @Brandon I've linked you to the docs. There is an `offset` parameter in `np.diag` that allows you to specify the row number from where to begin extracting diagonal elements. We want to move down the rows in steps of 3 (in this case), that's what `range` does.

Comment: `range(0, *x.shape)` is pretty opaque code to give to a beginner, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.  What he's doing is taking the `shape` (`(6, 3)` in this case) and appending it to the arguments of `range`, so that `range(0, *x.shape)` becomes `range(0, 6, 3) - > [0, 3]`.  The `*` unpacks the tuple, so without it the result would be, `range(0, (6, 3))` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need heavy library like [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) to achieve this simple task. In plain python you can do it via using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.cycle(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) as:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle

>>> my_list = [[2,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,4], [6,0,0], [0,7,0], [0,0,8]]
>>> for i, j in zip(my_list, cycle(range(3))):
...     print(i[j])
...
2
3
4
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Why have cols at all? It's always the same as rows, right?

```
for rows in range(6):
    print(matrixA[rows,rows])
```

Comment: If `matrixA` was square,  but that isn't the case.